# Does Internet Explorer 10 support WebGL?

Tags: internet-explorer, webgl, internet-explorer-10

I haven't used Internet Explorer in a long time and noticed some buzz regarding Internet Explorer 10. I've tried downloading it, but it seems I will need to install Windows 8, which I won't bother with on my limited bandwidth.

Has anyone tried Internet Explorer 10 and can tell me if it supports WebGL or not?

Comment: IE 10 under Windows 8 Developers Preview doesn't have WebGL support

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Internet Explorer 10 doesn't support WebGL.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL):

> Microsoft has not announced any plans to officially support WebGL.
>
> In June 2011, Microsoft announced that they could not endorse WebGL in its current form from a security perspective. Analysis performed by its MSRC Engineering team concluded that WebGL support in Microsoft products would have difficulty in meeting the requirements of the Security Development Lifecycle, the software security standards internally enforced in Microsoft. Specifically, Microsoft cited overly permissive exposure of hardware functionality, heavy reliance on third parties to secure web experience, and unproven denial-of-service protection capabilities as their key concerns.

[IEWebGL](http://iewebgl.com/) can be installed as a plugin.

Comment: So, you're willing to use a WebGL plugin in light that there may actually be security concerns?

Comment: lol. as we all know microsoft is so particular about browser security.

Comment: So we bash them constantly about their browser being insecure, but then when they show a genuine interest in security, we... still bash them?

Comment: @DavidBrown yup.... because they ruined the web for a decade

Comment: @DavidBrown It's not completely "genuine" even if partially true. It's more likely that it's because OpenGL (which WebGL is based off) is a direct competitor of DirectX (from Microsoft). Don't be surprised if they release a "WebDX" sometime soon.

Answer (score 2):

IE 10 does not support WebGL. Microsoft's released a [statement regarding their security concerns with WebGL](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2011/06/16/webgl-considered-harmful.aspx):

> We believe that WebGL will likely become an ongoing source of hard-to-fix vulnerabilities. In its current form, WebGL is not a technology Microsoft can endorse from a security perspective.
>
> We recognize the need to provide solutions in this space however it is our goal that all such solutions are secure by design, secure by default, and secure in deployment.

WebGL is [supported in IE 11](http://fremycompany.com/BG/2013/Internet-Explorer-11-rsquo-s-leaked-build-395/).

Comment: You just repeated the same information Jonas posted 2 years ago.  Why would you link to a random website instead of a Microsoft website talking about WebGL support?

Comment: @Ramhound, clearly Jonas has covered the question with his answer, but when I came here looking for answers I didn't find a genuine citation from MS, only one from Wikipedia. So I added one -- nothing wrong with adding more information. I couldn't find a genuine statement from MS about IE 11, so gave the best link I could. Can you find a better one? Thanks for the downvote.